# What is the 5.19 kernel support window in 22.04 (jammy)?

Tags: kernel, 22.04, lts

I found 2 ubuntu.com pages showing a similar graph, but with different end-of-support dates:

1. https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle#ubuntu-kernel-release-cycle
2. https://ubuntu.com/kernel/lifecycle

(1) has a line tagged as `5.19 kernel Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS` showing a standard support window (orange) ending sometime in 2027.

(2) has a line tagged as `Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (v5.19)` showing a very short support window ending in 2023 (this year).

I also noticed 6.2 kernels appear in 22.04 repos.

So, (a) was 5.19 an HWE kernel, currently replaced by 6.2, or (b) are both 5.15 and 5.19 LTS kernels on 22.04?

Comment: seems to me 1 is 22.04 the lts with hwe stack ending at the 5 year normal cycle for an lts. and 2. is 22.10 = 22.04.2 ending after the 6 months cycle for a normal release.

Comment: @Rinzwind, if 1 is 22.04 LTS + HWE why does it mention that 5.19 support ends in 2027? IIUC [1], we don't really know which HWE kernel will end up being supported until 22.04 LTS is supported because it will be the GA kernel used in the next LTS (24.04) which is in the future. [1] https://ubuntu.com/blog/canonical-livepatch-gets-even-better-now-supporting-hardware-enablement-kernels

Comment: @VLD your have presented two conflicting documents, asked "which is correct?" and received the (correct) answer. We are not Canonical employees, and need not justify any mistakes they make in their writings.

Comment: I didn't mean to sound like I blaming anyone - sorry. I was genuinely hoping it is going to be an LTS kernel. (I need something newer than 5.15 on my servers, but not willing to take the burden of keeping up with the rolling HWE.)

Comment: @VLD when Ubuntu 22.04 reaches 22.04.5 LTS it will be using a LTS kernel that will be supported until the EOL of Ubuntu 22.04, but that's still in the future... till then it'll use the non-LTS kernels from later release (5.19 from 22.10, 6.2 from 23.04, *mantic* is currently 6.3 but that's not expected to be the release kernel so it'll move to whatever 23.10 is released with etc).  Read the kernel team's blogs about their plans/dates.. as they're giving *cycle* updates in advance (giving details of what's ahead for *mantic* etc - best clue I've read thus far; do note Release team is ~6 weeks)

Answer (score 0):

The 5.19 kernel is from [Ubuntu 22.10 which is EOL in a few weeks](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/06/14/ubuntu-22-10-kinetic-kudu-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-20-2023/), before then Ubuntu 22.04 LTS will move from 5.19 to the 6.2 kernel from Ubuntu 23.04

It's been visible for package queries for a few days now.. eg.

```
linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04-edge | 6.2.0.23.23~22.04.4   | jammy-proposed   | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, s390x
```

As always, it appears in *edge* first, then will progress through testing to the main kernel package and roll out to systems.  The current ETA is [July 2023](https://ubuntu.com/blog/canonical-livepatch-gets-even-better-now-supporting-hardware-enablement-kernels) .

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS offers two kernel stacks supported for the life of the product

- GA or the initial 5.15 kernel (*the most stable option thus default for server installs, or some flavors with 22.04 & 22.04.1 media*)
- HWE which currently is 5.19, will move to 6.2 and advance from kernels from non-LTS & the next LTS release (*ie. the GA kernel stack from 24.04 LTS is the final kernel*).  See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack for details.

Comment: If you want 6.2 earlier & are willing to use a kernel still in the testing phase, you can add the *edge* kernel, or it'll be next seen as *proposed* before finally rolling out in July 2023.  Once it's rolled out, the 5.19 will stop being a *supported* kernel though.

Comment: Also note:  Ubuntu has OEM kernel options, and if the 5.19 is used as an OEM kernel it'll have extended support I've not covered whilst being used as an OEM kernel. Sorry I don't monitor OEM kernels (*don't use them myself & little news is published about them via Ubuntu News*) so I'm unaware of 5.19 being used by OEM though don't recall seeing it.